# Is there an Instagram API that has "Archive post" feature?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I wanted to write a program that would archive all posts from account, but I cannot find this feature in InstaPy. Is there an API that would have such feature?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Instagram Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api, it does not look like there is currently a way to archive/unarchive posts.